# Strange import path for internal npm package

Tags: typescript, npm

I have the below `package.json` that I use for building and pushing to an internal package registry:

```
{
  "name": "@internal/my-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Test package",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "bin": {
    "my-project": "./dist/src/index.js"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/src/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/src/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./models": {
      "import": "./dist/src/models/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/src/models/index.d.ts"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --project tsconfig.build.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
  "volta": {
    "node": "18.16.1",
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://internal.com/"
  }  
}
```

and the following file tree:

```
my-project
  src/
   -> lib/
   -> models/
     -> my-model.ts
     -> index.ts
   -> index.ts
  package.json
```

And with this in `dist`:

```
my-project
 -> dist/
     -> src/
       -> lib/
       -> models/
       -> index.js
       -> index.d.ts
     -> tsconfig.build.tsbuildinfo
```

And **tsconfig.build.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "composite": true
  },
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "dist/**/*"
  ]
}
```

and **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "lib": [
      "ES6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.build.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

I then build and pack to a local tgz archive. But when I install it in another project:

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@internal/my-project": "file:../../../my-project/internal-my-project-0.0.0.tgz"
  }
}
```

and import types from `MyModel` it looks like this:

```
import { IModel } from '@internal/my-project/dist/src/models/my-model';
...
```

I would expect something like this:

`import { IModel } from '@internal/my-project';`

Am I misconfiguring the package or is this expected behaviour?

I would expect that I can import types without the full path in the package

Answer (score 1):

> Am I misconfiguring the package?

Arguably yes.

> Is this expected behavior?

Yes...the way you've set it up. If you want to be able to do just `import { IModel } from '@internal/my-project';` then you'll need to set the entry point as the `main` property in the package.json of the internal package. Alternatively, since you seem to have subfolders, you could use an exports map:

```
{
  "name": "@internal/my-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Test package",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "bin": {
    "my-project": "./dist/src/index.js"
  },
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./models": {
      "import": "./dist/models/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/models/index.d.ts"
    }
  },
  ...and so on
}
```

With this setup `import { whatever } from '@internal/my-project';` will get you exports from src/index and `import { whatever } from '@internal/my-project/models';` will get you the exports of `src/models/index`. Note that if `src/index` already imports and re-exports the exports of `src/models/index` you don't need to do all this, just make `main` point to `./dist/index.js` and `types` point to `./dist/index.d.ts` or wherever you have your type declarations compiled to.

NOTE: if you use the `exports` map feature, node will ignore your `main`, so you don't need both. Also note that export map makes some assumptions about what you tsconfig looks like, but it should be pretty close.

Comment: I have updated my example based on your suggestion but the import in the other projects still only works with the full path `import { IModel } from '@internal/my-project/dist/src/models/my-model';
` Is there something else I need to change?

Comment: @codeshare they will have to update their dependency to the latest version of your shared package, but then it should absolutely work. Maybe edit the question with your latest package.json for the shared package?

Comment: Yep the package was updated and removed node_modules + clean install. Hm maybe it’s because my dist folder has the src subfolder ?

Comment: Are you importing files outside the src directory?

Comment: No right now I am only importing this type: `import { IModel } from '@internal/my-project/dist/src/models/my-model'` in my test project. I suspect that something is going wrong during the bundling/packaging of the library project. Also updated post with package.json for the test project

Comment: @codeshare no, I mean are you doing that _in the internal package_. Typescript should not be recreating your src directory inside of dist if all of your files are in /src

Comment: Oh when specifying the import path manually in VS code it also finds the `IModel` if I specify: `import { IModel } from '@internal/my-project/dist/src`. So seems I can use both paths. And no in the "internal" package I don't have imports to anything outside src/ folder. If I update my tsconfig.json to  `"rootDir": "./src",` I no longer get the src folder as subfolder in dist. But now I have tsconfig.build.tsbuildinfo file in the root of the repo each time I build the project

Comment: @codeshare that's fine. Just make sure to put it in your .gitignore and your .npmignore, it isn't important for publishing. Once that's done though, you should not need the `/dist/src` stuff, the `exports` map should just make everything work. Don't forget that you can use `npm link` to test it out locally with your downstreams without having to actually publish to test changes.